# MS Asure ios remote notifications. Wrong API documentation?

Tags: ios, azure

I am trying to launch iOS remote notifications with Azure service, but official pages
https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/mobile-services-dotnet-backend-ios-get-started-push/

and provided framework has totally different (mismatched) API. Do I miss something?

https://github.com/Azure/azure-mobile-services/tree/master/sdk/iOS/

Comment: UPDATE: I downloaded framework from version 1.*, than built WindowsAzureMessaging.framework and after that I continue with MS official recommendations

Answer (score 0):

Anton.
Maybe this link would help (Updated 14.03.2016): https://azure.microsoft.com/ru-ru/documentation/articles/notification-hubs-ios-get-started/

P.S. There are 2 different realizations.
Look here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/jj927170.aspx

1) You can generate deviceToken and just register your device on azure notification hub, using iOS SDK. Then you use your backend only for notifications send (you push notification on notification hub and it resolves which devices must receive your message)

2) You generate deviceToken on device, but don't use any SDK on device. Just send this token on some api on your backend. And this api register your device on otification hub.

May be you should try second method for your goals)